# PPPoS configurations for the lwIP Stack

Tags: freertos, rtos, lwip, ppp

I am working on the lwIP stack with the ATSAMV71 microcontroller.
I would like to configure the lwIP stack in PPPoS mode using a TCP/IP connection.
Will you please help me to know,

1. What is required #define the configurations required to put the lwIP stack into PPPoS mode?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [STM32 LWIP PPPos implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42116869/stm32-lwip-pppos-implementation)

Answer (score 1):

```c
/*
   ---------------------------------
   ---------- PPP options ----------
   ---------------------------------
*/
#define PPP_SUPPORT                              1
#define PAP_SUPPORT                              1
#define LWIP_DNS                                 1

/*
   ---------------------------------
   --------- GPRS options ----------
   ---------------------------------
*/
#define GPRS_DEBUG                               LWIP_DBG_OFF
#define GPRS_SUPPORT                             1
#define GPRS_TYPE                                1
#define GPRS_OWNTHREAD                           1
#define GPRS_THREAD_NAME                         "pppos"
#define GPRS_RUNTIME_APN                         1
#define GPRS_RUNTIME_PIN                         1
#define GPRS_COMMAND_DELAY                       500
#define GPRS_ICCID                               1
#define GPRS_THREAD_STACKSIZE                    512
#define GPRS_THREAD_PRIO                         2
#define GPRS_PPPIF_NAME_0                        'P'
#define GPRS_PPPIF_NAME_1                        '0'
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, Have you implemented this? if yes, Will you please share any reference link with the application code or reference guide?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share the code, but what I did is that I used this repo in my project with the SIM900 GPRS module https://github.com/MarioViara/gprs . I also ported the sio_read() and sio_write() functions to read and write from uart.

Comment: @shivpatil That is a bit of a ["Google it for me" request](https://www.google.com/search?q=PPPoS+lwip) and probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67048191/stm32-lwip-pppos-getting-started.  It is also not in your original question - you asked for the `#define`, you got the `#define`.  If you have a new question post a new question rather than running a conversation in _comments_.  Extending this question after it has been _completely_ answered by Bayrem would be bad form IMO as it would render his answer incomplete after then event.